# Latching with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, led, capacitor, resistors, latch

I am struggling to have the circuit below working on LTspice. Indeed, as I understand it when the switch is pressed the LED should change it's state (turn on if off / turn off if on). The switch is pushed every 600 ms for 50 ms and from one push to the next the state of the LED should change.

The problems I have are the following:

1. The circuit is not behaving as expected: LED is always on except when the push-button is pushed (see image below)
2. I don't know what to change in order to achieve what I am looking for. Especially, I have a problem understanding when the P-MOSFET should be "On" with respect to that circuit (i.e. what should be the approximate voltage reading on the gate to turn it on/off).
3. I don't understand how the values of resistors and capacitor affect the desired output.

Thank you for your help,

Best,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

LED addition into the latch is one issue. It's forward voltage being higher than NMOS threshold voltage does not allow the latch to change state. If you short the LED, it could work.

You can then use a buffer to drive the LED instead of inserting it into the latch circuit as shown below

[image]

With regard to your question about PFET, it is ON if it's gate voltage is 0V and it is OFF if it's gate voltage is equal to Vcc2.

((R4+R5) || R6)-C2 time constant is critical for resetting the latch. It needs to be high enough so that it C2 keeps the gate of M4 lower than it's threshold voltage for a sufficient time until the latch gets fully reset.

R5 needs to be high enough so that when the switch is closed, the steady state gate voltage of M4 is lower than the threshold voltage. This could also be the issue. You could increase R5 to 100k or higher and see if it fixes the issue. However, if R5 is high, the wait time needed between setting the latch ON and OFF will be higher because C2 needs to be at 0V before you can turn ON the switch to reset the latch.

For further inputs, uploading the .asc file will help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, that was extremely helpful. I have a much better understanding now. For your eyes only, see the simulation I performed below. I also had to change the value of the capacitor (to lower the time constant).

[image]